# Using a physical ISA graphics card in a virtual machine

Tags: graphics-card, virtual-machine

So I want to set out to setup a highly functional Windows 98 gaming setup within my Ubuntu installation. Where my question arises is from my understanding of these two points:

A) USB devices are recognized by my Windows 98 virtual machine.
B) ISA-to-USB adapters are available.

So if I were to connect a graphics card to an ISA-to-USB adapter, plug that into my laptop, and boot up my Windows 98 VM, would Windows 98 recognize the graphics card?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not, unless Windows 98 knows how to use that ISA-to-USB adapter.

In general, it is possible for the host to pass control of hardware to the guest. But I doubt that there is enough demand for ISA cards to do this. Some VM hosts don't even support Windows 98.

Comment: I have gotten a Windows 98 VM up and running thankfully, however, this particular ISA-to-USB adapter I'm looking at says it is compatible with DOS and Windows XP (among a great deal of other things) which is what makes me wonder if this would work. Maybe I'll just take the risk, buy the adapter, and see what happens.